# Javascript to jQuery convert code

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm having difficulty in changing the following code to use jQuery.  Could anyone point me in the right direction?

```
function addListItem() {
    var listItem, container, dataList = document.getElementById('dataList');

    // Create our list item
    listItem = document.createElement('div');
    listItem.setAttribute('data-bb-type', 'item');
    listItem.setAttribute('data-bb-img', 'images/icons/icon11.png');
    listItem.setAttribute('data-bb-title', 'Title ');
    listItem.innerHTML = 'My description';

    // Create a dummy container
    container = document.createElement('div');
    container.appendChild(listItem);

    // Apply the styling
    bb.imageList.apply([container]);

    // Append the item
    dataList.appendChild(container.firstChild);

    // re-compute the scrolling area
    if (bb.scroller) {
        bb.scroller.refresh();
    }
}
```

Comment: perhaps you could post your attempt at jQuery, and we could help work through the problems you encountered. You're more likely to get help that way than simply asking for someone to do it for you.

Comment: http://docs.jquery.com/Main_Page

Comment: Why do you need to convert it to jquery anyway? Seems like it's perfectly good javascript to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, let me tell you that your code looks perfectly fine.

Now, to select an element by its ID using jQuery, use the [**ID Selector (“#id”)**](http://api.jquery.com/id-selector/). Thus, instead of using `document.getElementById("dataList")`, you'd use:

```
$("#dataList")
```

To create DOM elements on the fly, use [`jQuery( html, props )`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery2). For example, to create your list item, you'd use:

```
listItem = $("<div />", {
  data-bb-type: 'item',
  data-bb-img: 'images/icon/icon11.png',
  data-bb-title: 'Title'
}).html("My description");
```

Finally, to append elements to another, use [`.append()`](http://api.jquery.com/append/). With this function, your dummy element creation could be done using the following:

```
container = $("<div />").append(listItem);
```